# Alter RavenDb created Database Bundles

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

How can I alter database bundles such as compression or any other bundle through Raven Studio or even via code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify them via the Database Settings, note that this is typically not a supported operations.
You can do that via the `Raven/ActiveBundles` settings.

Comment: Sir in your documents there's warning telling Activating or disabling compression on an already existing database will cause DB malfunction. would you please explain what sort of malfunction we should expect?

Comment: That is what it meant by unsupported operations. Some of the bundles aren't meant to be turned on & off, and may exhibit strange behavior.

Comment: In other words, do try to avoid doing this.

Comment: What if we create new database with enabled compression bundle and smuggle data from the other one to the new one? Is this do the trick without harm?

Comment: Yes, that is the supported way to do this.